# Read contents of a previous Fedora hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, disk

I have this Fedora 18, Spherical Cow OS which has not been very stable. So I am migrating to Ubuntu 11.10

I need to read the contents of the disk, so I can copy all my development files there. How can I do that. It seems when I plug the disk as external USB disk, I don't get to see the partition mounted?

Comment: The only File System I see for this disk using Gparted is ext4 and lvm2.... the ext4 partition is able to be mounted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Fedora uses LVM. By default, the Ubuntu live (desktop) does not have have lvm support, but you can install it and then mount the Fedora partition.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lvm2
```

Now list and mount your lvm partition / data

List your physical volumes

sudo pvscan

List your volume groups
    sudo vgscan

Activate all volume groups available.
    suod vgchange -a y

Again run lvscan to show your active volumes.

```
sudo lvscan
```

Mount the partition to /mnt ( get this information from the above commands )

```
sudo mount /dev/VolGroupXXX/LogVolXXX /mnt
```

You should now be able to access your data in the /mnt directory

Comment: thanks now i am able to copy the files from the partition